# Is it possible to change particle explosion element size in time?

Tags: particles

I'm using particles, explode modifier and a texture to control particles emition timing.

I'm wondering is it possible to change the exploded element size in time from the particle emission start until the end of particle lifetime (or any other timing).

[image]